# How to define a method only when class generic type satisfies a test?

Tags: kotlin, generics, overloading, partial-specialization

I am trying to do something like the following:

```kotlin
class Event<TPayload>() {

  fun subscribe(handler: (payload: TPayload) -> Unit) { ... }

  fun subscribe(handler: () -> Unit) where TPayload : Unit { ... }

}
```

The intention is that instances of `Event<Unit>` will have two overloads of `subscribe()`, but other instances will only have one.

The above code will not compile. I tried using extension methods, but would have to use a different name for the extra method, rather than overloading it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define that second function as an extension function so it only appears for Events who have a type of Unit. It's okay to overload the function name. Define it outside the class:

```
inline fun Event<Unit>.subscribe(crossinline handler: ()->Unit) = 
    subscribe { handler() }
```

Test:

```
class Event<T> {
    private val subscribers = mutableListOf<(T)->Unit>()

    fun subscribe(handler: (payload: T) -> Unit) {
        subscribers += handler
    }

    fun send(payload: T) {
        for (subscriber in subscribers) subscriber(payload)
    }

}

fun main() {
    val event = Event<Unit>()
    // Using verbose syntax to prove it's the extension function being used
    // and not a lambda with implicit 'it':
    event.subscribe(fun() { println("got unit") })
    event.send(Unit)
}
```

If you use a lambda, the compiler will use the first `subscribe` function with an implicit `it` parameter since it takes precedence in overload resolution. But runtime behavior would be the same either way if you aren't using the parameter.

Comment: Huh. I wonder why it seemed I couldn't overload using extension methods then. Maybe it was the lambda issue. Very irritating, the lambda limitation. And I can't make *all* the methods extensions, because they'd have nothing to call to get the work done.

Comment: I mean, it wouldn't matter which one the lambda bound to, *if it worked*. But it doesn't. The lambda binds to the first method, and then refuses to compile because "the signature doesn't match". What kind of nonsense is this?